# Python Regex Search and Count with Symbol Character

Tags: python, regex, string

i try to make some script with python to find and count a word in string. A word is "@sosiora", i have find some example but it's not find "@sosiora" but "sosiora". Here is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
words = ["@sosiora"]
exactMatch = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % '\\b|\\b'.join(words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print len(exactMatch.findall("@riky ini adalah @sosiora dengan huruf s "))
```

I don't know but it's always print 0. Please help me, i'm newbie in Python. Thank you

Extra :
I had edit my code now, but i found some problem again. how to extract the word if i have found them ? here is my code now

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                           
import re                                                                                                 
words = ["@sosiora","@sosiora#1","@sosiora#2","@sosiora#3","@sosiora#4","@sosiora#5"]
exactMatch = re.compile('|'.join(words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print len(exactMatch.findall("@riky ini adalah @Sosiora#1 dengan huruf s "))
```

if i found "@sosiora#1" or "@sosiora#2", how to extract the number? because i need that number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex you're compiling is wrong... This should work better:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
words = ["(@sosiora#(\d+))"]
exactMatch = re.compile('|'.join(words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
text = "@riky ini adalah @Sosiora#1 dengan huruf s"

m = exactMatch.findall(text)
print 'Found %d matches' % len(m)
print 'First word found: ' + m[0][0]      # @Sosiora#1
print 'First index found: ' + m[0][1]      # 1
```

Comment: oh yeah...but how to make it not case sensitif? soon i will, i can't accepting the answer now, i have to waiting for 5 minutes,

Comment: Edited my answer... just add the IGNORECASE flag as you did before.

Comment: now i found some problem again. how to extract a word from a string ? i mean like @sosiora#1 or @sosiora#2. how to extract the number?

Comment: The findall method returns a list of the matched words, so if you did:

m = exactMatch.findall("@riky ini adalah @sosiora dengan huruf s ")

Then m will be a list of matched words

Comment: but how to split the number? like @sosiora#1 or @sosiora#2 ? because i need that number.. i had editing my code.

Comment: @elcicko did you want the number only or the whole string?

Comment: i mean if i found that string, then it split the number. example : if i found "@sosiora#1", so i can use the number "1", or "@sosiora#2" so i can use "2".

Comment: I edited the answer. I changed the regex's in words to also match the number after the '#' character. Now findall returns a list of tuples, each tuple in the list is the matched group. So, m[0] in the example above is the first match, m[0][0] is the first matched group (entire word) and m[0][1] is the second matched group (number).

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Python; your regex itself is wrong.

The GREP code `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) – that is, it will match if on *one* side there is a "word character" and on the *other* side there is none. The character `@` is not a word character (it does not get matched with `\w`) and so your regular expression is expecting something like `abc@sosiora` (with a word character *left* of the `@`).

Fix it by removing the left `\b` from your regular expression.

Comment: it's just working now, but how to split the number of the string? i have editing my code.

Comment: @elcicko: well that's a new question, unrelated to your original one.

Comment: @kasra, `\b` matches between a word char and a non-word char, vice-versa. So there is no possibility of getting word boundary `\b` between start of the line and `@` or space and `@` since both are considers as non-word chars. `\B` is a well suited one, which does the opposite of `\b`